# Swiping the Fly-in sliding menu android

Tags: android, menu, sliding

I'm new to programming android, I'm trying to make the effect of sliding menu with your finger, followed several tutorials over the internet but got no success, I found this library on the Internet, it works by clicking on the button, I have the same effect when sliding the finger. Thank you in advance for your help!

## *LayerStack.java*

```
package com.example.slideoutmenu;

import com.example.slideoutmenu.LayerStack;
import com.example.slideoutmenu.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LayerStack extends Activity {

    //Declare
    private LinearLayout slidingPanel;
    private boolean isExpanded;
    private DisplayMetrics metrics; 
    private ListView listView;
    private RelativeLayout headerPanel;
    private RelativeLayout menuPanel;
    private int panelWidth;
    private ImageView menuViewButton;
    Button menu1, menu2,menu3,menu4 ;
    TextView txtpays;
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams menuPanelParameters;
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams slidingPanelParameters;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams headerPanelParameters ;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams listViewParameters;
    ImageView lampada;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layer_stack);      
        //Initialize
        metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        panelWidth = (int) ((metrics.widthPixels)*0.80);

        headerPanel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);
        headerPanelParameters = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) headerPanel.getLayoutParams();
        headerPanelParameters.width = metrics.widthPixels;
        headerPanel.setLayoutParams(headerPanelParameters);

        menuPanel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuPanel);
        menuPanelParameters = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) menuPanel.getLayoutParams();
        menuPanelParameters.width = panelWidth;
        menuPanel.setLayoutParams(menuPanelParameters);

        slidingPanel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.slidingPanel);
        slidingPanelParameters = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) slidingPanel.getLayoutParams();
        slidingPanelParameters.width = metrics.widthPixels;
        slidingPanel.setLayoutParams(slidingPanelParameters);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listViewParameters = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) listView.getLayoutParams();
        listViewParameters.width = metrics.widthPixels;
        listView.setLayoutParams(listViewParameters);

        //Slide the Panel   ;
        //lampada = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagelampada);
        menu1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu_item_1);    
        txtpays = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listepays);  
        menu2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu_item_2);
        menu3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu_item_3);
        menu4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu_item_4);
        txtpays.setText("Clique acima para acessar o menu");

        clicabotao();


        //listaClica();

        menuViewButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menuViewButton);     
        menuViewButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!isExpanded){
                    expandMenu();                                   
                }else{
                    expandList();               
                }              
            }
        });

    }   
    //############################################# FUNÇÃO CRIA MENUS CLICK ##########################################
    //    função: executar codigo individual de ação ao clicar em botão do menu aposentos   
    public void clicabotao(){

        // CONFIGURA ONCLICK DOS BOTÕES MENU
        menu1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                    txtpays.setText("Clique acima para acessar o menu");
                    expandList();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.i("Mensagem ",""+e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });      
        menu2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub        
                try{
                    txtpays.setText("Clique acima para acessar o menu");
                    expandList();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.i("Mensagem ",""+e.getMessage());
                }


            }
        });
        menu3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{

                    txtpays.setText("Clique acima para acessar o menu");

                    expandList();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.i("Mensagem ",""+e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
        menu4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{

                    txtpays.setText("Clique acima para acessar o menu");
                    expandList();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.i("Mensagem ",""+e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
    }
    //############################################# FUNÇÃO CRIA ITEM DA LISTVIEW #############################################
    //############################################# FUNÇÃO EXPANDE MENU APOSENTOS #############################################
    public void expandMenu(){
        new ExpandAnimation(slidingPanel, panelWidth,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.75f, 0, 0.0f, 0, 0.0f);
        isExpanded = true;
    }
    //############################################# FUNÇÃO EXPANDE A LISTVIEW ############################################
    public void expandList(){
        new CollapseAnimation(slidingPanel,panelWidth,
        TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.80f,
        TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, 0, 0.0f, 0, 0.0f);
        isExpanded = false;
    }
    class ListViewItem{
        public int ThumbnailResource;
        public String Title;
        public String SubTitle;
    }
}
```

## *ExpandAnimation.java*

```
package com.example.slideoutmenu;

import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;

public class ExpandAnimation extends TranslateAnimation implements Animation.AnimationListener{

    private LinearLayout slidingLayout;
    int panelWidth;

    public ExpandAnimation(LinearLayout layout, int width, int fromXType, float fromXValue, int toXType,
            float toXValue, int fromYType, float fromYValue, int toYType, float toYValue) {

        super(fromXType, fromXValue, toXType, toXValue, fromYType, fromYValue, toYType, toYValue);

        //Initialize
        slidingLayout = layout;
        panelWidth = width;
        setDuration(400);
        setFillAfter( false );
        setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        setAnimationListener(this);
        slidingLayout.startAnimation(this);
    }


    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

        //Create margin and align left
        LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) slidingLayout.getLayoutParams();
        params.leftMargin = panelWidth;
        params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;     
        slidingLayout.clearAnimation();
        slidingLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        slidingLayout.requestLayout();

    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {

    }

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {

    }

}
```

## *CollapseAnimation.java*

```
package com.example.slideoutmenu;

import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;


public class CollapseAnimation extends TranslateAnimation implements TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener{

    private LinearLayout slidingLayout;
    int panelWidth;

    public CollapseAnimation(LinearLayout layout, int width, int fromXType, float fromXValue, int toXType,
            float toXValue, int fromYType, float fromYValue, int toYType, float toYValue) {

        super(fromXType, fromXValue, toXType, toXValue, fromYType, fromYValue, toYType, toYValue);

        //Initialize
        slidingLayout = layout;
        panelWidth = width;
        setDuration(400);
        setFillAfter( false );
        setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        setAnimationListener(this);

        //Clear left and right margins
        LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) slidingLayout.getLayoutParams();
        params.rightMargin = 0;
        params.leftMargin = 0;
        slidingLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        slidingLayout.requestLayout();       
        slidingLayout.startAnimation(this);

    }
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

}
```

## *activity_layer_stack.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_bg">

    <!-- Menu Panel -->
    <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/menuPanel"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="right"
           android:background="@drawable/agua_menu"
           android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/menu_title_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" 
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"             
                android:gravity="center_vertical"                
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="@string/menu_title">   
            </Button>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/menu_item_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"             
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/menu_title_1"          
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Cozinha">     
            </Button>     
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/menu_item_2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"                          
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Sala">
            </Button>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/menu_item_3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"          
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Suite">
            </Button>
          <!--  <View
                android:id="@+id/menu_item_divider_4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_3"
                android:background="#353535"/>  -->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/menu_item_4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"          
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Quarto Hospedes">
            </Button>
            </RelativeLayout>

       <!-- Sliding Panel -->     
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/slidingPanel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/fundo_branco" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/menuViewButton"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/description"
                            android:src="@drawable/icon_menu1"
                            android:visibility="visible" />


                </RelativeLayout>
                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/listepays"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_divider_2"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"  
                    android:textColor="#00BFFF"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#550022" >
                    </TextView> 
            <View
                android:id="@+id/listaDivide"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/menuViewButton"
                android:background="#000000"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/listaDivide2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/listepays"
                android:background="#000000"/>  




        </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: So what do you want? What's the issue?

Comment: have you looked at this http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Yes already studied about navigation drawer but this example I put the question would be a little different, my application already uses this architecture sliding menu, it would be necessary to implement this function only swipe as in the example this site:
http://www.cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/29/the-making-of-prixing-2-swiping-the-fly-in-app-menu/
I studied this site but do not quite understand, I am beginner.

Comment: JoelFernandes the problem is that this application I move the sliding clicking a button, I would like to move it through the finger movement.